# rendering partial using jquery in js.erb file giving error. render is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

below is code in file '`app_erb.js.erb`'

```
$(function(){
    $('.add_more_element').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('.remove_this_element').show('slow');
        $(this).hide('slow');
        $(this).closest('.form-group').add('<%=j render 'resumes/resume_certification' %>');
    });
});
```

and i have partial  `views/resumes/_resume_certification.html.erb`

but when i load my app it gives me 
NoMethodError at /resumes/new
undefined method `render'.

What i am missing in the whole process for rendering a partial using javascript.

Comment: Try using `double-quotes` `"<%=j render 'resumes/resume_certification' %>"`

Comment: Tried getting the same error.

Comment: At which line did the error pops up?

Comment: The error will likely be that you're trying to use `render` in your JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JS**

I believe the problem you have is that you're trying to load an `ERB` / `Rails` method from your asset pipeline.

Although the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) does say you *can* use ERB preprocessing in your asset pipeline, it is scant on how to implement this feature:

> The asset pipeline provides a framework to concatenate and minify or
>   compress JavaScript and CSS assets. It also adds the ability to write
>   these assets in other languages and pre-processors such as
>   CoffeeScript, Sass and ERB.

It's my understanding that including ERB / Rails code directly in your asset pipeline is a no-no because of the dynamic complexities it brings (at least that's been my experience). Instead, you'll want to keep your JS as "native" as possible

--

**Ajax**

Secondly, you have to realize something very important - Javascript is front-end. It's designed to bind events to your [`DOM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) elements, and does not interact with the Rails back-end directly.

As such, you're going to need to use AJAX to pull the data you need from the server:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :resumes do
   collection do
       get :resume_certification
   end
end

#app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb
Class ResumesController < ApplicationController
   def resume_certification
      render "resumes/resume_certification"
   end
end

#app/assets/javascripts/app.js
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".add_more_element", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('.remove_this_element').show('slow');
        $(this).hide('slow');

        $.get( "resumes/resume_clarification", function( data ) {
           $(this).closest('.form-group').add(data);
        });  
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I got it now. your answer will help many.

Answer (score 1):

The best option I see is to avoid loading the partial directly into a string, but to load said page trough ajax (that would also avoid you loading said partial without using it until the function is called!)

```
$(function(){
    $('.add_more_element').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        el = $(this);
        el.siblings('.remove_this_element').show('slow');
        el.hide('slow');
        $.get("<%= resume_certification_path %>", function(data) {
            el.closest('.form-group').add(data);
        });
    });
});
```

I replaced the $(this) with a new var to avoid messes inside the ajax call. Obviously this solution requires you to create a new get route, and set

```
render :layout => false
```

inside the new action you'll use to render that partial.

Comment: Despite I got my edit to Rich refused (and I can't comment its answer), I'd like to point out that:
1)  `$.get( "resumes/resume_clarification"[...]` may lead to errors if the script isn't called from the root url, therefore using path helpers may be better not also to avoid that error but also to have a no issues if you happen to change the route to the specific action.
2) `$(this)` inside the $.get callback won't refer anymore to the clicked element.

Pointing that out so others can diagnose their problems if they copy/paste the above code